# Repeating Titles in headers when storing SQL data in table

Tags: php, html, sql

When trying to display a table which has SQL data present, the rows at the top of the table are repeating, which I do not want to happen! I know it is probably something stupid but I've tried for a while to solve this and can't. Images outline the code which I used, and the output which is displayed

[image: Output to the user]

[image: Code which was used.]

Comment: Please paste your actual code, not a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1):

Write the first `<tr></tr>` before while

like this :

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>
<th>albul Name</th>
..
..
..
</tr>";
while($album=$stmt->fetchObject()) {
echo "<tr>
<td>$album->$album_name
...
...
</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're echoing your Header row inside of your WHILE loop, so you're writing the header for each iteration of the loop.

To fix, move the header row out of your loop like this:

```
echo "<table><tr>
<th>album Name</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Genre</th>
<th>Artist Name</th>
<th>Total Running Time</th>
</tr>"
while ($album = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
//Display the data as a row.
    echo "<tr>
    <td>$album->album_name</td>
    <td>$album->year</td>
    <td>$album->genre</td>
    <td>$album->artist_name</td>
    <td>$album->total_time</td>
    </tr>"
}//end loop
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're looking at something for too long you just can't see it anymore. Just take your  tags out of the while loop. You only need to the data rows in the loop.

Comment: Most definitely, it was such an easy fix! Credit to Mohammed El Banyaoui :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the  code out of the WHILE loop.

The first row  and  should be before the loop code starts

Answer (score 0):

you need change your code is firts set your struture html table and next php code:

```
<?php
echo"
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>ALBUM</td>
      <td>YEAR</td>
      <td>GENERE</td>
      <td>ARTIST</td>
      <td>TOTAL PLAYING TIME</td>
    </tr>
";
```

now you need print your records from db

```
while($album=$stmt->fetchObject()) {
echo "<tr>
<td>$album->$album_name</td>
<td>$album->$year</td>
<td>$album->$genre</td>
<td>$album->$artist_name</td>
<td>$album->$total_time</td>
</tr>";
}//end while
```

all code is this:

```
    <?php
    echo"
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>ALBUM</td>
          <td>YEAR</td>
          <td>GENERE</td>
          <td>ARTIST</td>
          <td>TOTAL PLAYING TIME</td>
        </tr>
    ";
while($album=$stmt->fetchObject()) {
echo "<tr>
<td>$album->$album_name</td>
<td>$album->$year</td>
<td>$album->$genre</td>
<td>$album->$artist_name</td>
<td>$album->$total_time</td>
</tr>";
}//end while
```